# replacing first content with php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, replace

```
    <?php
require_once('wp-load.php');

function replace_first_paragraph($content, $replacement_text) {
    $paragraphs = explode('<p>', $content);
    $paragraphs[1] = '<p>' . $replacement_text . '</p>';
    $modified_content = implode('<p>', $paragraphs);
    return $modified_content;
}

function batch_replace_paragraphs() {
    // Read the CSV file
    $csv_file = fopen('urls.csv', 'r');
    if ($csv_file === false) {
        die('Could not open CSV file.');
    }

    // Iterate through each entry in the CSV
    while (($data = fgetcsv($csv_file)) !== false) {
        $post_id = $data[0];
        $replacement_text = $data[1];


        $mycontent = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);

        if ($mycontent) {
            $modified_content = replace_first_paragraph($mycontent, $replacement_text);
            // Update the post content with modified content
            wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_content' => $modified_content));

            // Output or save a message indicating the modification
            echo "Updated content for post ID $post_id.\n";
        }
    }

    fclose($csv_file);
}
batch_replace_paragraphs();
```

?>

The code above instead of replacing the first paragraph it inserts the text from csv at the bottom of post. I am looking for solution on how i can tweak the code to replace the first paragraph.

Comment: Your best bet is to parse the content with an [HTML-aware parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/231316) which will allow you to make that specific target.